# Iptables - specify range

Tags: iptables

I am new to IPtables.  I have added the following lines in my router to redirect DNS request to openDNS.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br0 -s 192.168.1.200 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.222
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br0 -s 192.168.1.200 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.222

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br0 -s 192.168.1.201 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.222
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br0 -s 192.168.1.201 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.222
```

I do have many lines like this for all the devices. I want to avoid this multiple lines.

Question is how do I specify range of IP (say `192.168.1.200` to `192.168.1.240`) in a single command (one for `tcp` and one for `udp`) line?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by replacing `-s` by `--src-range`

ex :

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br0 -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.200-192.168.1.240 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.222
```

You can also do the entire 192.168.1.0/24 network with

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.222
```

source : iptables man page https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables

Comment: Thanks!.  Do I need to add  '-m iprange' before '--src-range'?.  I saw some posts which says that I need to add '-m iprange'.

Comment: @yogi_en yes, sorry, I forgot that part, I'm editing

Comment: The above command doesn't seems to be working.  I tried this in my dd-wrt router and didn't work as expected.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That command is working on my ubuntu. I don't have my my dd-wrt on hand to test.

Comment: OK.  Will check again.

Comment: Tried again wth the following exact comments.      iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br0 -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.200-192.168.1.240 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.222  and iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br0 -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.200-192.168.1.240 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.222.   It didn't work in the dd-wrt router.

Comment: From ddwrt docs :  
  Many builds do not have the iprange match but you can use clever subnet masks to accomplish something similar as well, if the range aligns well on subnet boundaries. You may also be able to download a version of iptables that includes the iprange match via Optware.       https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Iptables_command